# I have no console output on boot ASROCK IMB-150

Tags: boot, display, hdmi, console, vga

No video on boot

I have a small industrial computer with an ASROCK IMB-150 Motherboard in it, running Ubuntu 14.04 server.  Ubuntu boots up fine, but if there isn’t a screen attached at boot time then there is no console video output on either the 15pin VGA connector or the HDMI.  SSH works, the system boots, I just have no video, I have updated the bios and cycled through the BIOS settings and toggled on an off all the various settings regarding the on board VGA adapter. I’m wondering if I can just set something like 1024x768 out on the VGA or HDMI port regardless of if a monitor is attached. I don’t want to have to install or, frankly, run a display manager when all I need is some text output.
Many thanks,
-Cory

LSPCI:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView SSA-CUnit (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView Gen7 (rev 0e)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView 6-Port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0e)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView SEC (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation ValleyView High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation ValleyView SMBus Controller (rev 0e)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

/etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash consoleblank=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x600
```

Comment: Can you show us grub options and boot command line?

Comment: I added /etc/default/grub.

Comment: Remove `quiet splash` from line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` then run `sudo update-grub`. Probably it should solve your problem.

Comment: I tried it, there still isn't any output on either the HDMI or VGA, adding to the strangeness, if I enter the grub menu without the monitor connected (restarting and hitting esc), when I plug the monitor in I have console and ubuntu finds the correct output when starting but only if the monitor was connected at some point while grub was running (I disconnected it and finished the boot in that order and I still had video after ubuntu was running).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASROCK IMB-150 has a lvds connector on the board, with no monitor connected  it defaults to the LVDS, despite LVDS being disabled in BIOS.

Disabling the LVDS and enabling the VGA port forced the output out the correct video port. 
adding consoleblank=0 solved a problem with the console not returning after the screen was blanked.

/etc/default/grub
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=LVDS-1:d video=VGA-1:e consoleblank=0"

see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/modedb.txt for more options